# Trouble with additional NIC: MSI MS250 PRO-VD + Logilink PC0029A

Tags: linux, network-adapter, irq

I recently changed Mobo/CPU/RAM on a PC where I used to have a dual-gigabit connection.

With the previous configuration, using the integrated LAN controller and a LogiLink PC0029A PCI-e expansion card, I configured Linux to merge two connections to a managed switch in a single connection (operation usually referred as bonding). It worked well.

But now, having installed a MSI MS250 PRO-VD motherboard, and the same PCI-e card on top of it, I noticed that Linux recognises only one NIC.

It seems strange, but:

- `lspci` only shows a NIC
- disabling onboard network from UEFI control panel leds to the same behaviour (only one NIC recognised)
- even if the onboard NIC is disabled, linux can activate a connection on the NIC it recognise, but that traffic flows on the cable connected to the onboard NIC
- in both cases, the same MAC address is shown

I've updated BIOS, checked for IRQ conflicts with `lsdev`, changed PCI-e slot, but no solution...

Note that both motherboard and expansion card make use of the same Realtek IC family (r8168 driver, already updated)

How can I investigate further? Could you provide some tips?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the problem was that the card wasn't recognized in the new mother board. Guess: The card wasn't correctly seated (or the slot was badly manufactured, so it's difficult to seat it correctly), and therefore the electric connections didn't work. All the other things you describe (bonded interfaces, MAC, drivers) don't play a role here.

Comment: By disabling onboard network card, I shouldn't be able to connect to the internet. Instead, a network card is still recognised. It is strange, seems that at least the toggle in the bios doesn't work properly.

Comment: Plugging the problematic Logilink card in the x16 slot worked. The x1 slots where I tested this card worked too with another network card from Tp-Link.

Comment: So definitely not a motherboard connectors problem IMO. Seems a software/firmware/logic problem to me...

Comment: "By disabling onboard network card, I shouldn't be able to connect to the internet. Instead, a network card is still recognised". Sorry, this makes no sense. Please clarify which cards are detected under which circumstances, where `lspci` shows them, etc. The cards (onboard and slot) should show up as *distinct* `lspci` entries, with *distinct* addresses. So which card(s) show up initially, which card(s) show up in 1x slot, which card(s) show up in 16x slot, which cards show up after you disable the internal card? That's what counts.

Comment: Excluding the x16 case (both network cards are detected), when I plug the logilink card in any of the x1 slots, only the onboard card is detected, indipendently from the enable/disable onboard network card toggle in the BIOS.

Comment: So that *does* sound like a "card not properly seated" problem - possibly the card connector is just at one end of the tolerances, and the 1x slots are at the other end, so they don't make proper contact for this particular card. PCIe device recognition has *nothing* to do with firmware or software, it's purely hardware.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get a TP-LINK Gigabit PCI-e card, and I experienced that this card works well if placed in the x1 slots where the Logilink failed to be recognised. I also found that by installing the Logilink card in the x16 PCI-e slot, it was recognised.

Conclusions:

- Try ALL slots, even larger than needed if you can.
- Test the same slot with another card, if you have a spare one.
- Probably MSI made some mistakes in the design of the firmware, and some conflicts were the cause of my troubles. Note that is not primary due to using the same NIC chipset, because I managed to start successfully the system with all the 3 NICs attached and recognised.
- I still don't know why even with the internal NIC disabled, its port worked with some strange collaboration provided by the expansion card, with a transparent behaviour for the OS (which continued to recognise the internal card and its MAC address).